# Capitalizing text in R with an exception list

Tags: r, regex

*Apologies, I should've been more clear (I really appreciate all the help though!)

I extract from a database a .csv file. This file contains a list of place names. I use INITCAP when I extract them so they are all proper mixed case. However some of these place names need to remain capitalized as they are know abbreviations, like universities, etc. The end result will be me putting this back into the database in a corrected format.

I'm new to R and stuck on a bit of a problem. I'm extracting data that is all in capitals but I need it to be proper case i.e. change, "THIS IS ALL CAPS" to "This Is All Caps" but I need to be able to exclude certain words. Things like "FYI" and other abbreviations need to remain capitalized. I've managed to solve some of my issue with the lettercase library, particularly str_ucfirst. My only remaining issue is the exception part. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a list of the words you want to exclude? You could use something like !(word %in% c(list of words to exlude))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on @akrun's (now deleted) solution you could form an exception vector which is then `paste0`d into a regular expression using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
string <- "THIS IS ALL CAPS"
exceptions <- c("FYI", "THIS")
pattern <- sprintf("(?:%s)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\b([A-Z])(\\w+)", paste0(exceptions, collapse = "|"))
gsub(pattern, "\\1\\L\\2", string, perl = TRUE)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "THIS Is All Caps"
```

Note the `THIS` which got ignored.

---

The pattern is

```
unimportant|not_important|(very important)
```

In terms of regex engines that support it, this is

```
...(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|what_i_want_to_match
```

In this case

```
\b      # a word boundary
([A-Z]) # uppercase letters
(\w+)   # [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

This is fed into the replacement subroutine.

Comment: Nice solution. Could you explain the `pattern` statement, please?

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
gsub("\\b([A-Z])(\\w+)", "\\1\\L\\2", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "This Is All Caps"
```

---

Or use `stri_trans_totitle` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_trans_totitle(str1)
#[1] "This Is All Caps"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "THIS IS ALL CAPS"
```

Comment: I think op want to add exceptions like fyi `str1 <- "THIS IS ALL CAPS FYI YO TTYL BRO"; gsub("(?|(FYI|TTYL)|\\b([A-Z])(\\w+))", "\\1\\L\\2", str1, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `stringr` package for camelcase conversion without using regular expressions:

```
library(stringr)

string <- "CONVERT THIS TO CAMELCASE, YO"
exceptions <- c("YO", "THIS")

paste(sapply(unlist(str_split(string, " ")), 
             function(word){ ifelse(word %in% exceptions, 
                                    word, 
                                    str_to_title(word))}),
      collapse = " ")
```

Output:

```
[1] "Convert THIS To Camelcase, YO"
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat slow and primitive but very tractable base-R solution:

```
string <- c("THIS IS ALL CAPS", "FYI only some words should be not all CAPS")
except <- c("fyi", "all")

string2 <- gsub("([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]+)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", string, perl = TRUE)
string2
[1] "This Is All Caps"                           "Fyi Only Some Words Should Be Not All Caps"

string3 <- string2
for (word in except) {
  string3 <- gsub(
    paste0("(", word ,")"), 
    "\\U\\1",
    string3, 
    perl = TRUE, 
    ignore.case = TRUE
  )
}
string3
[1] "This Is ALL Caps"                           "FYI Only Some Words Should Be Not ALL Caps"
```

Comment: Thanks snoram. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. I went with snoram's which worked for what I was trying to do.

(R)ock on.